# Add Category Taxonomy Support to Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm writing some code that makes extensive use of custom post types- and I'm looking for a means of programatically adding a category to a defined custom post type, and then accessing its category ID.

I had a poke around but I can't seem to find a robust means of achieving this - wp_create_category would be the obvious choice but of course this doesn't support custom post types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to pre-create some terms you can add the following into the init function that registers the taxonomy.  it will create the term foo in the recordings taxonomy

```
if (!term_exists( 'foo', 'recordings') ){
        wp_insert_term( 'foo', 'recordings' );
    })
```

Comment: That's perfect! Is there any way of getting the ID of the created term? I didn't word my question especially well so many thanks.

Comment: well wp_insert_term returns the term and taxonomy IDs see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Return_Values  you could also use get_term_by : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Answer (score 11):

Inside your `register_post_type` you can add the `taxonomies` parameter.

```
register_post_type('discography',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
             //your label stuff
             ),

  'taxonomies' => array('recordings', 'category', 'whatever'),  //add this....

  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => true,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
  'query_var' => true
        )
  );
```

Alternatively you can use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` , http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type

Answer (score 4):

**Please put this code in theme functions.php**

```
function post_type_discog() {

register_post_type('discography',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Discography' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Discography' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Discography' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Discography' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Discography' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Discography' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Discography' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Discographys' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Discographys found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Discographys found in Trash' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Discography' ),
        ),
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'query_var' => true
        )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'post_type_discog');

add_action( 'init', 'create_discog_taxonomies', 0 );

function create_discog_taxonomies()
{
  // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Recordings', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Recording', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Recordings' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Recordings' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Recordings' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Recording' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Recording:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Recording' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Recording' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Recording' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Recording Name' ),
  );
  register_taxonomy('recordings',array('discography'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'recordings' ),
  ));
}
```

*In this code u can create custom post type and custom category type. May this code is helpful to u.*

Comment: Thanks - but that's the bit I've already got. What I now need is to add actual categories (in this case, add actual recordings)